# How to get click, double tap, and long click gestures for a view inside a gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview, onlongclicklistener, gesturedetector

I have ImageViews inside of a GridView, I had been using an OnItemClickListener along with an OnItemLongClickListener set on the GridView to open the image on a larger page and to delete the item respectively.  Now, I have to implement rearranging of the ImageViews in the GridView, so I plan to move the deletion function to a double tap gesture, (please do not lecture me on android style guidelines (including the possibility of contextual actionbars, which I suggested), as this is what my boss asks for to emulate functions inside our ios app) in order to reserve long click for the drag and drop. I set an OnTouchListener on each view in the getView of my custom adapter, feeding a GestureDetecter with a listener extending SimpleOnGestureListener the given MotionEvent with onTouchEvent.  I know what to do up to that point, but when I included (onDown of course, to get other callbacks) onDoubleTap, onSingleTapConfirmed, and onLongPressed all taps were interpreted as long clicks. And when I removed the both callback methods to be replaced with their listener counterparts once again (ie OnItemClickListeners) I received those two gestures but not the double tap, which makes sense, as double taps start out as a single tap unless you wait for a bit less than a second to confirm them as singles rather than potential doubles. I also tried placing the OnItemClickListener, but not the OnItemLongClickListener, with the callback in the extended SimpleOnGestureListener. In this case, only long presses were ever interpreted, but other gestures caused no response. Here is my code as it stands now, and do note that I returned false in the onTouchEvent in order to allow others (itemclicklisteners) to consume the events following the attempts made in the GestureDetector.

```
public class MainBoardGridAdapter extends GenericBoardGridAdapter implements OnItemLongClickListener {
    private class Ges extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        int pos;
        public Ges(View v) {
            pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent me) {
            //this does get called but none of these methods below
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent me) {
            new DeleteConfirmationPrompt(c, "board") {
                @Override
                protected boolean onDeleteConfirmed() {
                    // delete the visionboard
                    return deleteBoard(pos);
                }
            }; // Constructor shows dialog
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            MainBoardGridAdapter.super.flagForUpdate(pos);
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onBoardClick(pos, getName(pos));
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(c, VisionBoardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(VisionBoardActivity.EXTRA_VISION_BOARD_NAME, getName(pos));
                frag.startActivityForResult(intent, MyBoardsFragment.REQUEST_EDIT);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        final int pos, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(c, "Long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return false;
    }
    // called by getView of extended adapter
    @Override
    public void onImageLoaded(ImageView iv, String data, View root) {
         iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               (new GestureDetector(c, (new Ges(v)))).onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
         });
    }
}
```

And in the Activity, gv is my GridView:

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(gridAdapter);
```

Also note that I had been using true in the return value in the GestureDetector methods, until trying the current configuration.There was no difference to be seen.
Thank you for your valuable time and help, I hope that someone will be able to point out what I am doing incorrectly.

-Jackson